# Node.js on Windows Git Bash shebang failure

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, git, bash

Windows Git Bash specific problem...

Pretty simple script which takes some user input, and does not echo it to the output. Works fine when called like `node secret.js` but acts strange when called as `./secret.js`, needing a ctrl+c to exit, and echoing the output as you type.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var prompt = require('prompt');

prompt.start();
prompt.colors = false;
prompt.message = '';
prompt.delimiter = ''; 

prompt.get([{
  name: 'secret',
  description: 'tell me your darkest secret: ',
  hidden: true
}], function(err, result){
    console.log('Hey guys! He said "' + result.secret.slice(0, 5) + '..." only kidding, I won\'t tell.');
});
```

What is a safe way to make script run on all platforms, including git bash?

update: added `env` result in case it is useful...

```
IEUser@ie8winxp MINGW32 ~/projects/issue (develop)
$ env
HOMEPATH=\Documents and Settings\IEUser
MANPATH=/mingw32/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/man:/share/man:
APPDATA=C:\Documents and Settings\IEUser\Application Data
HOSTNAME=ie8winxp
SHELL=/usr/bin/bash
TERM=xterm
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel
WINDIR=C:\WINDOWS
TMPDIR=/tmp
OLDPWD=/c/Documents and Settings/IEUser/projects
USERDOMAIN=IE8WINXP
OS=Windows_NT
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\Documents and Settings\All Users
TEMP=/tmp
COMMONPROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files\Common Files
USERNAME=IEUser
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PATH=C:\Documents and Settings\IEUser\projects\issuemd\node_modules\.bin:C:\Documents and Settings\IEUser\projects\issue\node_modules\.bin:C:\Documents and Settings\IEUser\projects\node_modules\.bin:/c/Documents and Settings/IEUser/bin:/mingw32/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw32/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Documents and Settings/IEUser/bin:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Documents and Settings/IEUser/Application Data/npm:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
EXEPATH=C:\Program Files\Git
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
PWD=/c/Documents and Settings/IEUser/projects/issue
SYSTEMDRIVE=C:
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
USERPROFILE=C:\Documents and Settings\IEUser
CLIENTNAME=Console
PS1=\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:${PWD//[^[:ascii:]]/?}\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$
LOGONSERVER=\\IE8WINXP
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
SSH_ASKPASS=/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass
SHLVL=1
HOME=/c/Documents and Settings/IEUser
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH
PLINK_PROTOCOL=ssh
HOMEDRIVE=C:
MSYSTEM=MINGW32
COMSPEC=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
TMP=/tmp
SYSTEMROOT=C:\WINDOWS
PROCESSOR_REVISION=170a
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/mingw32/lib/pkgconfig:/mingw32/share/pkgconfig
ACLOCAL_PATH=/mingw32/share/aclocal:/usr/share/aclocal
INFOPATH=/usr/local/info:/usr/share/info:/usr/info:/share/info:
PROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files
DISPLAY=needs-to-be-defined
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=1
SESSIONNAME=Console
COMPUTERNAME=IE8WINXP
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Comment: What is the shebang there for? You're already calling it with node.

Comment: the shebang is there for when I want it to be called as a command, same as any other time you would put a shebang there

Comment: Ah I read that as node secret.js and node ./secret.js. If you want it truly cross-platform you shouldn't use a shebang at all. Without cygwin (or similar) you won't have shebang support at all in windows.

Comment: @BrandonSmith so how should I be doing it? I am planning to publish through npm, and want it to work everywhere node js does.

Comment: If it's in npm and you want to be able to call it directly, it should have a CLI and be installed globally. For example, npm install -g xo installs xo globally and then the user can simply call "xo" anywhere.

Comment: Those issues don't sound like shebang issues. They sound like terminal/etc. issues. Does that difference happen in the same shell session/terminal instance?

Comment: @EtanReisner I tried in `cmd` instead of `git bash` (which is MINGW32) and it works ok - no idea where to start looking for the problem :-/ I pasted `env`

Comment: I also tried installing cygwin, and encounter the same problem exactly.

Comment: Both versions work correctly from a `cmd` prompt? But only the `node ...` version works in the `git bash` prompt?

Comment: @EtanReisner `node secret.js` works fine from `cmd` but of course `./secret.js` does nothing on it's own - however, when packaged up with npm (assuming `"bin": {"secret": "secret.js"}` specified in `package.json`) and installed with `npm i -g .` (from within project root) then run with `secret`, it is fine - so yes, works fine from `cmd`, and is broken in `git bash` and `cygwin`.

Comment: You were the one who said `./secret.js` acts oddly. Not me. So if that wasn't a meaningful statement you should probably have stated that more correctly in the first place. So the installed version is broken in git bash and the cygwin shell? Does `less "$(type -p secret)"` show you your script or some node loader script?

Comment: @EtanReisner I have found an easier way to reproduce the same problem, is to do `npm init` and accept default answers. From `cmd` it works as expected, but from `git bash` or `cygwin` it hangs after the final question (`Is this ok? (yes)`) and requires ctrl+c to exit - same as for my script. This is from within new directory, with default setup of all software.

Comment: Following the thread - I found that running `C:\cygwin\cygwin.bat` within `cmd`, then it all works fine too, which seems to point at this being same issue as this: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6459 which is something to do with node not running correctly on mintty - which is probably the common factor between cygwin and git bash.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out [cygwin is not supported by node](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6459#issuecomment-27673308) (and I assume git bash too).

Seems that [git bash is not a real tty](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/issues/272#issuecomment-138375494).

Looks like someone did something about it by [bundling winpty with git bash](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3006#issuecomment-167375054).

### Solution...

From within `git bash`, run `winpty bash`, then rest should work as expected.